# Stored Procedure returning different results with no changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a large stored procedure which contains a cursor and some rounding. When I run the stored procedure and look at the allotment column the number will change by a dollar sometimes without any changes to the SQL code. So I can run the query, check a record and see $10300 a few times then it will switch to $10299 then back etc. It's not consistent across all records either. The records that are accurate or off can be in any combination every time I run the procedure.

Seems completely arbitrary and I've never seen anything like this in all the years I've been working with SQL. My guess is that it's the rounding but I would still expect it to work the same way every time. I'd be grateful for any thoughts or ideas to try. Thank you!

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetDatabase] 

-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@FY as CHAR(4),
@Obj_det as CHAR(3),
@Agy_Obj as CHAR(2),
@ArchiveId as INT
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @temp TABLE (   FY CHAR(4), 
                        PCA CHAR(5), 
                        Index_No CHAR(4),                           
                        Obj_det CHAR(3), 
                        Agy_obj CHAR(2), 
                        Appro_sym CHAR(3), 
                        Fund_src CHAR(1), 
                        Fund_No CHAR(4), 
                        Method CHAR(1), 
                        Project CHAR(6), 
                        [Char] CHAR(1),
                        Allotment NUMERIC(14,0))

DECLARE @RecordId as INTEGER,
        @CurrentFY CHAR(4),
        @CurrentPCA CHAR(5),
        @CurrentIndex_No CHAR(4),           
        @CurrentObj_det CHAR(3), 
        @CurrentAgy_obj CHAR(2),
        @CurrentAppro_sym CHAR(3), 
        @CurrentFund_src CHAR(1), 
        @CurrentFund_No CHAR(4), 
        @CurrentMethod CHAR(1), 
        @CurrentProject CHAR(6), 
        @CurrentChar CHAR(1),
        @CurrentAllotment NUMERIC(14,0),
        @CurrentSumAllotment NUMERIC(14,0),
        @CurrentPcainAllotment NUMERIC(14,0),
        @PreviousRecordId as INTEGER,
        @PreviousFY CHAR(4),
        @PreviousPCA CHAR(5),
        @PreviousIndex_No CHAR(4),          
        @PreviousObj_det CHAR(3), 
        @PreviousAgy_obj CHAR(2),
        @PreviousFund_src CHAR(1), 
        @PreviousFund_No CHAR(4), 
        @PreviousMethod CHAR(1), 
        @PreviousProject CHAR(6), 
        @PreviousChar CHAR(1),
        @PreviousAllotment NUMERIC(14,0),
        @PreviousSumAllotment NUMERIC(14,0),
        @PreviousPcainAllotment NUMERIC(14,0),
        @getUplfile CURSOR

SET @getUplfile = CURSOR FOR
SELECT          (ROW_NUMBER()

                 OVER (ORDER BY     FY,
                                    PCA,
                                    Index_No,
                                    Obj_Det,
                                    Agy_Obj) )as    RowNumber, 
                                                    FY, 
                                                    PCA, 
                                                    Index_No,
                                                    obj_det, 
                                                    agy_obj, 
                                                    Appro_sym, 
                                                    Fund_src, 
                                                    Fund_No,
                                                    Method,
                                                    Project,
                                                    [Char],
                                                    Allotment,
                                                    SumAllotment,
                                                    PcainAllotment

FROM            (SELECT     a.fy,
                            a.pca,
                            a.index_no,
                            a.obj_det,
                            a.agy_obj,
                            a.appro_sym,
                            a.fund_src,
                            a.fund_no,
                            a.method, 
                            a.project,
                            a.[char],
                            a.ALLOTMENT,
                            c.allotment as SumAllotment,
                            b.Allotment as PcainAllotment
                FROM        (SELECT     tblpcain.fy,
                                        tblpcain.pca,
                                        tblpcain.index_no,
                                        tblpcain.obj_det,
                                        tblpcain.agy_obj,
                                        tblpcafl.appro_sym,
                                        tblpcafl.fund_src,
                                        tblpcafl.fund_no,
                                        tblpcafl.method, 
                                        tblpcafl.project,
                                        tblappro.[char],
                                        ROUND(SUM(CASE
                                                    WHEN    tblpcain.obj_det = @Obj_det AND 
                                                            tblpcain.agy_obj = @Agy_Obj AND 
                                                            tblpcain.pca between '05000' AND '05999' THEN   CASE
                                                                                                                WHEN tblpcafl.fund_src = 'F' THEN  tblpcain.allotment * tblpcafl.W_PNCT
                                                                                                                ELSE 0
                                                                                                            END
                                                    ELSE    tblpcain.allotment * tblpcafl.pnct

                                                END),2) as Allotment

                            FROM        tblpcain, 
                                        tblpcafl,tblappro
                            WHERE       tblpcain.fy + tblpcain.pca = tblpcafl.fy + tblpcafl.pca AND
                                        tblpcafl.fy + tblpcafl.appro_sym = tblappro.fy + tblappro.appro_sym AND
                                        tblpcain.fy = @FY AND
                                        tblpcain.archiveid = @ArchiveId AND
                                        tblpcafl.archiveid = @ArchiveId AND
                                        tblappro.archiveid = @ArchiveId
                            GROUP BY    tblpcain.fy,
                                        tblpcain.pca,
                                        tblpcain.index_no,
                                        tblpcain.obj_det,
                                        tblpcain.agy_obj,
                                        tblpcafl.appro_sym,
                                        tblpcafl.fund_src,
                                        tblpcafl.fund_no,
                                        tblpcafl.method,
                                        tblpcafl.project,
                                        tblappro.[char]) as a LEFT JOIN
                            tblpcain as b ON a.fy = b.fy AND  a.index_no = b.index_no AND  a.pca = b.pca AND  a.obj_det = b.obj_det AND  a.agy_obj = b.agy_obj LEFT JOIN
                            (SELECT     fy,
                                pca,
                                index_no,
                                obj_det,
                                agy_obj,
                                SUM(allotment) as allotment
                            FROM        (SELECT     tblpcain.fy,
                                                    tblpcain.pca,
                                                    tblpcain.index_no,
                                                    tblpcain.obj_det,
                                                    tblpcain.agy_obj,
                                                    tblpcafl.appro_sym,
                                                    tblpcafl.fund_src,
                                                    tblpcafl.fund_no,
                                                    tblpcafl.method, 
                                                    tblpcafl.project,
                                                    tblappro.[char],
                                                    SUM(ROUND(CASE
                                                            WHEN    tblpcain.obj_det = @Obj_Det AND 
                                                                    tblpcain.agy_obj = @Agy_Obj AND 
                                                                    tblpcain.pca between '05000' AND '05999' THEN   CASE
                                                                                                                        WHEN tblpcafl.fund_src = 'F' THEN  tblpcain.allotment * tblpcafl.W_PNCT
                                                                                                                        ELSE 0
                                                                                                                    END
                                                            ELSE    tblpcain.allotment * tblpcafl.pnct

                                                        END,0)) as Allotment
                                        FROM        tblpcain, 
                                                    tblpcafl,tblappro
                                        WHERE       tblpcain.fy + tblpcain.pca = tblpcafl.fy + tblpcafl.pca AND
                                                    tblpcafl.fy + tblpcafl.appro_sym = tblappro.fy + tblappro.appro_sym AND
                                                    tblpcain.fy = @Fy AND
                                                    tblpcain.archiveid = @ArchiveId AND
                                                    tblpcafl.archiveid = @ArchiveId AND
                                                    tblappro.archiveid = @ArchiveId
                                        GROUP BY    tblpcain.fy,
                                                    tblpcain.pca,
                                                    tblpcain.index_no,
                                                    tblpcain.obj_det,
                                                    tblpcain.agy_obj,
                                                    tblpcafl.appro_sym,
                                                    tblpcafl.fund_src,
                                                    tblpcafl.fund_no,
                                                    tblpcafl.method,
                                                    tblpcafl.project,
                                                    tblappro.[char]) as MyData
                            GROUP BY    fy,
                                        pca,
                                        index_no,
                                        obj_det,
                                        agy_obj) as c ON a.fy = c.fy AND  a.index_no = c.index_no AND  a.pca = c.pca AND  a.obj_det = c.obj_det AND  a.agy_obj = c.agy_obj) As Data


OPEN @getUplfile
FETCH NEXT FROM @getUplfile
INTO    @RecordId,
        @CurrentFY,
        @CurrentPCA,
        @CurrentIndex_No,           
        @CurrentObj_det, 
        @CurrentAgy_obj,
        @CurrentAppro_sym, 
        @CurrentFund_src, 
        @CurrentFund_No, 
        @CurrentMethod, 
        @CurrentProject, 
        @CurrentChar,
        @CurrentAllotment,
        @CurrentSumAllotment,
        @CurrentPcainAllotment              

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    If  @CurrentSumAllotment <> @CurrentPcainallotment AND 
        (@CurrentFY <> @PreviousFY OR 
        @CurrentPCA <> @PreviousPCA OR 
        @CurrentIndex_No <> @PreviousIndex_No OR 
        @CurrentObj_Det <> @PreviousObj_Det OR 
        @CurrentAgy_Obj <> @PreviousAgy_Obj)
        BEGIN               
            SET @CurrentAllotment = @CurrentAllotment + (@CurrentPcainAllotment - @CurrentSumAllotment)
        END

    SET @PreviousFY = @CurrentFY
    SET @PreviousPCA = @CurrentPCA
    SET @PreviousIndex_No = @CurrentIndex_No
    SET @PreviousObj_det = @CurrentObj_Det
    SET @PreviousAgy_obj = @Currentagy_obj


    INSERT INTO @Temp ( FY, 
                        PCA, 
                        Index_No,                           
                        Obj_det, 
                        Agy_obj, 
                        Appro_sym, 
                        Fund_src, 
                        Fund_No, 
                        Method, 
                        Project, 
                        [Char],
                        Allotment)
    SELECT  @CurrentFY,
            @CurrentPCA,
            @CurrentIndex_No,           
            @CurrentObj_det, 
            @CurrentAgy_obj,
            @CurrentAppro_sym, 
            @CurrentFund_src, 
            @CurrentFund_No, 
            @CurrentMethod, 
            @CurrentProject, 
            @CurrentChar,
            @CurrentAllotment

    FETCH NEXT FROM @getUplfile
    INTO    @RecordId,
            @CurrentFY,
            @CurrentPCA,
            @CurrentIndex_No,           
            @CurrentObj_det, 
            @CurrentAgy_obj,
            @CurrentAppro_sym, 
            @CurrentFund_src, 
            @CurrentFund_No, 
            @CurrentMethod, 
            @CurrentProject, 
            @CurrentChar,
            @CurrentAllotment,
            @CurrentSumAllotment,
            @CurrentPcainAllotment
END

CLOSE @getUplfile
DEALLOCATE @getUplfile

SELECT      FY, 
            PCA, 
            Index_No,                           
            Obj_det, 
            Agy_obj, 
            Appro_sym, 
            Fund_src, 
            Fund_No, 
            Method, 
            Project, 
            [Char],
            Allotment
FROM        @Temp
ORDER BY    FY,
            PCA,
            Index_no,
            Obj_det,
            Agy_obj
```

END

Comment: Two things. 1) you really need to start using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around now for 25 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins 2) Why are you using a cursor here? They are horribly inefficient. This whole process looks like it could be as simple as a single select statement.

Comment: So basically you offer me no help at all other than to criticize my syntax. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't just criticize your syntax, I suggested a much better way to get your data. For the issue at hand it is nearly impossible to help. You have a massive query doing aggregation on a column and we don't know the datatype. It is tblpcain.allotment * tblcafl.pnct. That is going to produce an implicit conversion to some datatype based on the datatype of those columns. If you can share that it would go a LONG way to allowing others to provide you some insight.

Comment: I think you've provided all the help you are able to provide. Thank you.

Comment: LOL so you are upset because I can't see your screen to help? Maybe you are summing a float which can give you periodic rounding errors like this. And turning this into a set based process instead of RBAR (row by agonizing row) would help not just the performance but the ability to maintain the code. If you are willing to provide the details I am willing to help. If not, well I doubt anybody can offer much in the way of advice. I apologize if I offended you by offering some improvements suggestions to your code. I truly hope you find a solution to your issue.